# Azure Split/Merge Service, is it still relevant?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cloud-services, azure-elastic-scale, azure-elastic-sharding

I have managed to get the C# and db setup using ListMappings.  However, when I try to deploy the split/merge tool to Azure cloud classic the service it states 'The requested VM tier is currently not available in East US for this subscription. Please try another tier or deploy to a different location.'  We tried a few other regions with the same result.  Do you know if there is a workaround or updated version?  Is the split / merge service even still relevant?  Has anyone got this service to run on Azure lately?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-overview-split-and-merge

Comment: I think "Azure cloud classic" things are really retired. Its not an answer or anything. Just an educated guess.

Comment: Seems to be older for sure.  The issue I am having is the source code is not open source and we are stuck using the .cspkg that Microsoft provides.  I really do not want to have to write T-SQL to move tenants between shards if this tool is already written.  It is just frustrating it doesn't work. I followed the instructions step by step.

Comment: tough luck is all i can say. perhaps, someone will post an answer. wait it out.

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/classic-vm-deprecation

Comment: Split-merge is only relevant if you plan to move keys between shard db's. Since the introduction of elastic pools several years ago, it has become better practice to create one shard db for each key, and therefore you never need to move data (just drop the db or move it in/out of elastic pool in order to control scale).

Comment: Thank you @JaredMoore Your response was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question on whether it is still relevant, in my opinion is ... no. [Split-merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-overview-split-and-merge?view=azuresql) is no longer relevant with the maturation of elastic pools.

Elastic pools with one data base per tenant seem the sustainable way to implement multi tenancy with legacy code.  The initial plan was to add keys to each of our tables to have multiple tenants per database.  Elastic pools give us the same flexibility without having to make breaking changes to our existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Late post here, but we are implementing ElasticScale for a client to split ~50 clients into a database-per-tenant model. I don't think the SplitMerge tool will be used over the long term, just for the initial data migration from one db to many shards, but it has been handy for that purpose. We are using the ElasticScale SDK to allow a single API to route queries to the appropriate shard(s) based on sharding key. Happy to compare notes with you if you are still working on this.